# enum for GT, GTE, EQ, LT, LTE operators

Tags: java

Is there a Java enum anywhere in the Java libraries for *greater-than*, *greater-than-or-equal*, *equal*, *less-than-or-equal*, *less-than* comparisons?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @OldProgrammer parsing command line arguments and executing SQL statements with <, <=, =, > or >= comparisons in them.

Comment: I am not sure if it is what you are looking for but every enum has `ordinal()` method which returns it position in enum class. Maybe use its result with `<` `<=` `==` `>` `>=`.

Comment: Can you provide an explicit example of what you want your program to do? Please provide example input and a description of what operations the program will perform.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It doesn't appear to be one. Fortunately, it's not too difficult to put one together.

```java
public enum Comparison {
    EQ("="), GTE(">="), GT(">"), LT("<"), LTE("<=");
    
    private final String value;
    
    private Comparison(String text) {
        this.value = text;
    }
    
    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```